# Fortran subroutine returns the input when called by R

Tags: r, fortran, subroutine

I have a 4D array in R and trying to interpolate between the levels in the 3rd dimension. For that, I'm using a Fortran subroutine shown below, it compiles perfectly but I run it in R it returns the same `output_array` passed into it.

The subroutine should loop over the cells and search for the location of a given key-value `input_vect` in the key values array `inputt_array`to interpolate to, three cases are applied :

1. It is less than all value, then assign `NaN`
2. Falls between 2 layers in the 3rd dimensions of `inputt_array`  then interpolate.
3. It is greater than all values assign the value at the level of greatest key value in `inputt_array`

```
    subroutine vint(input_array,input_vect,inputt_array,m,n,o,p,req,output_array)
    implicit none
    integer :: m,n,o,p,req
    integer :: x,y,z,t,l
    double precision :: input_vect(req),input_array(m,n,o,p),inputt_array(m,n,o,p)
    double precision :: delta_w,delta_p,grad_w_p,diff_p
    double precision, intent(out) :: output_array(m,n,req,p)
    real :: arg = -1.0
    do l = 1,req
     do t = 1,p 
      do x= 1,m
       do y =1,n 
        do z=1,o    
!above uppest level
          if(input_vect(l) .LT. inputt_array(x,y,o,t)) then 
          output_array(x,y,l,t) = sqrt(arg) 
              end if 
! in between levels
          if(input_vect(l) .GE. inputt_array(x,y,z,t) .AND. input_vect(l) .LE. inputt_array(x,y,z+1,t) ) then 
            delta_w =  input_array(x,y,z+1,t) - input_array(x,y,z,t)
            delta_p = inputt_array(x,y,z+1,t) - inputt_array(x,y,z,t)
            grad_w_p = delta_w /delta_p
            diff_p = inputt_array(x,y,z+1,t) - input_vect(l)
                        output_array(x,y,l,t) = input_array(x,y,z+1,t) +  grad_w_p * diff_p 
              end if  
! extrapolation below the lowest level  
              if(input_vect(l) .GT. inputt_array(x,y,1,t)) then
            
                   output_array(x,y,l,t) = input_array(x,y,1,t)   
              end if
            end do 
           end do 
        end do  
       end do
      end do   
     end subroutine vint
```

However, it returns the input unchanged!

EDIT : This is how the subroutine is implemented in R. Another point, it seems it works but not for all cells of the array!

```
>   dim(input_array)
[1] 175  88  31   5
>   dim(inputt_array)
[1] 175  88  31   5
>   #load vertical interpolate subroutine 
>   dyn.load("example.so")
>   #check
>   is.loaded("vint")
[1] TRUE
 
>   DIM<-dim(input_array)
 
>   output_DIM<-c(DIM[1],DIM[2],length(input_vect),DIM[4])
>   output_array<-ff(array(0.00,dim =output_DIM),dim =output_DIM)
>   result<- array(.Fortran("vint",
                         input_array=as.numeric(input_array[]),
                         input_vect=as.numeric(input_vect),
                         inputt_array=as.numeric(inputt_array[]),
                         m=as.integer(DIM[1]),
                         n=as.integer(DIM[2]),
                         o=as.integer(DIM[3]),
                         p=as.integer(DIM[4]),
                         req = as.integer(length(input_vect)),
                       output_array=as.numeric(output_array[]))$output_array,
                dim =output_DIM)
> all(result == output_array[])
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the fortran you are using? It uses the variables plev and s which you have not declared, and as such fails to compile. If the routine is in a module and plev and s are available by host association it may be OK, but you don't indicate that Also terminating Do 15 with End Do is not valid fortran.

Comment: Also negative arguments to sqrt are illegal. Use ieee_value in ieee_arithmetic to generate a NaN

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I have edited the posted subroutine and tested with `gfortran -c -ffree-form example.f ` and  `R CMD SHLIB example.f ` and complied okay, however, is still returning the input

Comment: Did you notice that if input_vect(l) > inputt_array(x,y,1,t), then output_array=input_array. Maybe your are just in that case. You should check.

Comment: It is supposed to that:  if the interpolation key value is greater than the key values in `inputt_array` assign the value (stored in `input_array`) of the greatest key-value `inputt_array`